# Scala: type variance and pattern matching between two equal types

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference

I was playing around the other day with making a class to handle some arithmetic operations (yes, I know numeric is coming out in 2.8) and found myself wondering how to simplify the following:

```
def Foo[A]( _1:A, _2:A ) = (_1, _2) match{
    case _1:Bar, _2:Bar => _1 + _2
    case _1:Baff, _2:Baff => _1 push _2
    case _, _ => None
}
```

so that I can do just

```
def Foo[A]( _1:A, _2:A ) = _1 match{
    case _1:Bar => _1 + _2
    case _1:Baff => _1 push _2
    case _ => None
}
```

Granted, I know that in declaring the function the way it's been declared that `_2`'s type could conceivably inherit from `_1`'s type, "A" could be a shared trait, or so on.  I know this means the compiler needs to protest to protect the code.  Is there a way to say "I want _1 and _2 to be the same extact class" so that I don't have to make the double `_1:Int, _2:int` declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Im misunderstanding you, but if you just want the two parameters to be required to be the same type, you can do something like the following:

```
def Foo[A,B >: A <: A](_1: A, _2:B) = ...
```

This specifies that `B` is both lower and upper type bounded by `A`, thus must be `A`. Thus it will only compile if `_1` and `_2` are of the same type.

Comment: I got home to try this out and it doesn't work.  It doesn't even compile.  It fails at the "+" if there's more than an overloaded method.  This something that will compile in 2.8?

Comment: I tried it on 2.7.7, but It should work on 2.8. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use overloading here instead.